# Unidentified files stored as Facebook cache

Tags: files, cache

I found several large files stored as Facebook cache in the emulated path. 
277_428_10_0_en_us_1013.0,%   is one example of close to 1,000 files. What are they? I believe I have had a my phone to have been ha ked or tapped by an ex-boyfriend and when I try to open these files it says I don't have they ability to open theses audio files. I have found several other hidden audio and video recordings he made secretly and these files make . E extremely nervous. Please can you help me?

Comment: Usually, Facebook, Instagram, Twitter, etc cache files on a device so that the next time you view a picture or video, it is not fetch because it is already on the device. Try changing some of the files to have `.jpg` or `.mp4` extensions, then open them.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague..

- Open Settings
- Open Apps
- Look through your apps and try to identify any suspicious applications
- Open Google Settings
- Open Google Play Protect
- Scan your device for any potential threats

  Using a RAT ( Remote Access Tool ) without permission is highly illegal and constitutes as invasion of privacy along with many others.

You should probably back up all your pictures and files you'd like to keep and do a factory reset ... After factory reset, reinstall your apps from the Play Store and put your files back on it.... This way you'll eliminate any hidden spyware.

Remember to place a Lock Screen on your device, and don't let your partner or EX partner touch your device again...

The cache files could potentially be used as a form of log, logging your activities online and offline.

In the past I have installed spyware on my partners device ( with her permission ) but I at least made sure she knew it was on, and she knew how to remove it if she wanted too... Maybe if you are going through some trust issues, they should be addressed and openly discussed with your partner.